# Perl while loop using read()

Tags: perl

I want to read a text file `data.txt` using `read`.
I would like to read the first four integers of each line at a time.

#### data.txt

```
line1 0101020102
line2 2010201001
line3 0201010201
```

The `line1` etc. are part of the file.

This is what I could do up to now

#### Perl

```
my $data;
my $IN;
my $n = 0;

$line = 1;

open($IN, '<', "data.txt") or die " Error";

while ( $line != 0 ) {
    seek($IN, 6, SEEK_SET);
    $line = read($IN, $data, 4);
    seek($IN, 0, SEEK_SET);
}
```

The problem is that using this `while` loop, Perl keeps reading the first line in an infinite loop.

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Why would it do anything else, when you `seek()` to the beginning of the file after every read?

Comment: Are you thinking that using `read` is a good idea here (it isn't) or are you simply experimenting with the operator?

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand what `seek()` does. With `SEEK_SET` as the third parameter, the second parameter is interpreted as the position to move to as measured from the start of the file. So every time you run this line:

```
seek($IN, 6, SEEK_SET);
```

It always moves to the seventh position in the file (which is, obviously, always on the same line). Then when you run this line:

```
seek($IN, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

It always moves back to the start of the file.

Initially, I thought the solution was to change `SEEK_SET` to `SEEK_CUR` (which interprets the second parameter as the amount to move relative to the current position) but it's a bit more complex than that. Here's how I got it to work:

```
seek($IN, 6, SEEK_CUR); # Move forward six spaces
$line = read($IN, $data, 4);
seek($IN, 7, SEEK_CUR); # Move forward seven places
```

But really, a regex is the best approach here.

```
while(<$IN>) {
    ($data) = /\s(\d{4})/;
    print "$data\n";
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't work on Windows, because you assume a single additional line terminator character whereas Windows uses two